# Bash check if USB device is bound in /sys

Tags: bash, drivers, usb, command

I have a bash script that bounds/unbounds an USB device by setting a driver's value in the `/sys` directory. Here are the commands:

`'X-Y.Z'` *is the device's address.*

**Bind device:**
`sh -c "echo 'X-Y.Z' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind"`

**Unbind device:**
`sh -c "echo 'X-Y.Z' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind"`

After doing is, I need my script to check if the device is bound or not.

I didn't find a way to read the `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind` and `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` files. Is there a command that could read those files?

Is there any other way that my bash script can know the the device is bound just by having the device `X-Y.Z` format address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you bind your device you will find it listed in the directory where you did the bind. But you can also look to see if the link `/sys/bus/usb/devices/X-Y.Z/driver` exists, in which case it points to the driver being used.

For example, for an ftdi serial usb device `3-2.4:1.0` currently bound to the ftdi_sio driver it appears in the driver directory and there is a link from the devices directory:

```
$ ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/
3-2.4:1.0  bind  uevent  unbind
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2.4:1.0/
...
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Aug 16 18:33 driver -> ../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio
```

After an unbind, it is no longer in the directory, and the driver link does not exist:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo 3-2.4:1.0 >/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/unbind '
$ ls /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ftdi_sio/
bind  uevent  unbind
$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2.4:1.0/driver
/bin/ls: cannot access /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2.4:1.0/driver: No such file or directory
```